# Remove reactive expression in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

My application works well with reactive expressions, but it's very slow.
I have two functions :

- FixData which cleans and fix my data (more than 500k rows), this function is slow
- PlotData which returns a ggplot graph and is reasonably fast

What I want to do first is importing my files and fixing my data whithout "reactive({})", for example my data will be named "mydata".
Secondly, I filter and represent "my.data" with reactive expressions.
What I want is to keep my data in memory and don't change it like do my current program.

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

#   observe({


  cp <- reactive({

    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    read.delim(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE,
               sep = "\t",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  })

  up <- reactive({

    inFile <- input$file2

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    read.delim(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE,
               sep = "\t",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  })

  tac <- reactive({

    inFile <- input$file3

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    read.delim(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE,
               sep = "\t",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  })




    GetData <- reactive({
      my.data <- FixData(data.cp = cp(), data.up = up(), data.tac = tac())

      ifelse(input$case1 == TRUE & input$case2 == FALSE,
             my.data <- my.data[my.data$CONSTRUCTEUR %in% manufacturer &
                                  my.data$TYPE_DE_TERMINAL %in% input$terminal.type, ],
             ifelse(input$case2 == TRUE & input$case1 == FALSE,
                    my.data <- my.data[my.data$TYPE_DE_TERMINAL %in% terminal &
                                         my.data$CONSTRUCTEUR %in% input$manufacturer, ],
                    ifelse(input$case1 == TRUE & input$case2 == TRUE,
                           my.data <- my.data[my.data$CONSTRUCTEUR %in% manufacturer &
                                              my.data$TYPE_DE_TERMINAL %in% terminal, ],
                           my.data <- my.data[my.data$CONSTRUCTEUR %in% input$manufacturer & 
                                                my.data$TYPE_DE_TERMINAL %in% input$terminal.type, ]
                           )))
      if(input$lte == TRUE){
        my.data <- my.data[my.data$LTE == "Oui", ]
      }

      ifelse(input$case3 == TRUE,
             my.data <- my.data[my.data$Cause %in% cause, ],
             my.data <- my.data[my.data$Cause %in% input$pb, ]                   
             )

      my.data

      })



    GetData2 <- reactive({


      if (input$compare == "yes"){

        cp2 <- reactive({

          inFile <- input$file4

          if (is.null(inFile))
            return(NULL)

          read.delim(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE,
                     sep = "\t",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
        })

        up2 <- reactive({

          inFile <- input$file5

          if (is.null(inFile))
            return(NULL)

          read.delim(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE,
                     sep = "\t",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
        })




      my.data <- FixData(data.cp = cp2(), data.up = up2(), data.tac = tac())

      ifelse(input$case1 == TRUE & input$case2 == FALSE,
             my.data <- my.data[my.data$CONSTRUCTEUR %in% manufacturer &
                                  my.data$TYPE_DE_TERMINAL %in% input$terminal.type, ],
             ifelse(input$case2 == TRUE & input$case1 == FALSE,
                    my.data <- my.data[my.data$TYPE_DE_TERMINAL %in% terminal &
                                         my.data$CONSTRUCTEUR %in% input$manufacturer, ],
                    ifelse(input$case1 == TRUE & input$case2 == TRUE,
                           my.data <- my.data[my.data$CONSTRUCTEUR %in% manufacturer &
                                                my.data$TYPE_DE_TERMINAL %in% terminal, ],
                           my.data <- my.data[my.data$CONSTRUCTEUR %in% input$manufacturer & 
                                                my.data$TYPE_DE_TERMINAL %in% input$terminal.type, ]
                    )))
      if(input$lte == TRUE){
        my.data <- my.data[my.data$LTE == "Oui", ]
      }

      ifelse(input$case3 == TRUE,
             my.data <- my.data[my.data$Cause %in% cause, ],
             my.data <- my.data[my.data$Cause %in% input$pb, ]                   
      )

      my.data
      }  
    })

   observe({

   if(input$compare == "no"){

     output$myChart1 <- renderPlot({

       my.plot <- PlotDataManBis(GetData(), 
                              var = input$variable)
       my.plot

     })

     output$myChart2 <- renderPlot({

       my.plot <- PlotDataTypeBis(GetData(), 
                               var = input$variable)
       my.plot

     })

     output$myChart3 <- renderPlot({

       my.plot <- PlotDataCauseBis(GetData(), 
                                var = input$variable)
       my.plot

     })

     output$resume <- renderDataTable({

       my.data2 <- GetData()
       my.data2
     },
     options = list(bSortClasses = TRUE, iDisplayLength = 10,
                    aLengthMenu = list(c(5, 10, -1), c('5', '10', 'All'),
                                       aoColumnDefs = list(list(sWidth=c("100px"),
                                                                aTargets=list(0)))

                    ))
     )

   }else{


    output$myChart1 <- renderPlot({

      my.plot <- PlotDataMan(GetData(), GetData2(),
                             var = input$variable)
      my.plot

    })

  output$myChart2 <- renderPlot({

    my.plot <- PlotDataType(GetData(), GetData2(),
                            var = input$variable)
    my.plot

  })

  output$myChart3 <- renderPlot({

    my.plot <- PlotDataCause(GetData(), GetData2(),
                           var = input$variable)
    my.plot

  })

  output$resume <- renderDataTable({

    my.data2 <- GetData()
    my.data2
  },
  options = list(bSortClasses = TRUE, iDisplayLength = 10,
                 aLengthMenu = list(c(5, 10, -1), c('5', '10', 'All'),
                                    aoColumnDefs = list(list(sWidth=c("100px"),
                                                             aTargets=list(0)))

                 ))
  )}})
  #   })  
})
```

Thank you,
Mos

Comment: You can just do `df <- read.delim("some file")` and access it throughout your app. You don't need to put it inside a reactive.

Comment: Can you be more explicit, beacause I have to keep **infile <- input$file1** for ui.r interface ? I'm disturbed, I always used reactive expressions so ..
Thanks

Comment: If you have to use an "input" variable, it must be done inside of a reactive context, as far as I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page should help you https://gist.github.com/wch/9606002. Basically, if you put an `actionButton` in your file, you can put an `isolate` bracket around your file input, so that the data won't changed each time an input is changed. Look at that page for more of the intricacies, but essentially you would have an `actionButton` next to where the user inputs the file and indicates that the button reruns the app with that new data. Then in your server.R, would place `input$nameofyouractionButton` as the first line within the reactive expressions where you import and fix you data, and then `isolate()` around the rest of the reactive expression. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, I was using submitButton, and didn't know this one ! I'm trying it and reply to you :)